# How to return from a looped asynchronous function with callback in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to write a function that:

1. Takes an array of URLs
2. Gets files from URLs in parallel (order's irrelevant)
3. Processes each file
4. Returns an object with the processed files

Furthermore, I don't need for errors in #2 or #3 to affect the rest of the execution in my application in any way - the app could continue even if all the requests or processing failed.

I know how to fire all the requests in a loop, then once I have all the data, fire the callback to process the files, by using [this insertCollection pattern.](http://metaduck.com/01-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html)

However, this is not efficient, as I shouldn't need to wait for ALL files to download before attempting to process them - I would like to process them as each download finishes.

So far I have this code:

```
const request = require('request');

const urlArray = [urlA, urlB, urlC];
const results = {};

let count = 0;
let processedResult;  

const makeRequests = function (urls, callback) {
    for (let url of urls) {
      request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          callback(error);
          return;
        }
        processedResult = callback(null, body)
        if (processedResult) {
          console.log(processedResult); // prints correctly!
          return processedResult;
        }
      })
    }
};

const processResult = function(error, file) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      results.errors.push(error);
    }

    const processedFile = file + `<!-- Hello, Dolly! ${count}-->`;
    results.processedFiles.push(processedFile);

    if (++count === urlArray.length) {
      return results;
    }
  };

const finalResult = makeRequests(urlArray, processResult);
console.log(finalResult); // undefined;
```

In the last call to `processResult` I manage to send a return, and `makeRequests` captures it, but I'm failing to "reign it in" in finalResult after that.

My questions are:

1. Why is this not working? I can print a well-formed `processedResult`
   on the last iteration of `makeRequests`, but somehow I cannot return
   it back to the caller (`finalResult`)
2. How can this be solved, ideally "by hand", without promises or the
   help of libraries like async?

Comment: Rolling your own adhoc async handling is a *terrible* idea. There's a reason `async` and `Promise` are a thing. [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: without promises or other libs? well, lots of callbacks, maybe some arrays, and counting, etc. it won't be easy pretty or maintainable. Promise.all on the other hand could be implemented into your current code with just 3-4 lines of code.

Answer (score -1):

The `makeRequests` function returns undefined to `finalResult` because that is a synchronous function. Nothing stops the code executing, so it gets to the end of the function and, because there is no defined return statement, it returns undefined as default.